# Does Firebase Function reading and writing to Firebase Realtime Database contribute to Firebase Realtime Download?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Realtime Database to store data for my app. For some server based processing, I am using Firebase Function to do a periodic operation to read the data from the Realtime Database and update it if necessary and write it back to the Realtime Database.

I wanted to ask whether does Firebase Function operation to both read and write back to Firebase Realtime Database will contribute to the Realtime Database download usage (as Realtime Database download usage is charged)?

Comment: Any CRUD operation from even cloud functions will be counted in usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading data from the Realtime Database into your Cloud Function is a charged operation.

Note that this only applies to data that you code explicitly read in your Cloud Functions code. The data that is used to **trigger** your Cloud Function, and is passed into your code in the `snapshot`, `change`, and `context` parameters, is not charged.

Also see:

- [Do firebase cloud functions involve costs for realtime db and firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071848/do-firebase-cloud-functions-involve-costs-for-realtime-db-and-firestore/50072350#50072350)

Comment: Hi, correct me if I'm wrong, but the question is also asking whenever the user writes to the DB. So does the 'write' and/or uploading data also being counted towards billing?

Comment: The answer is really clear since the firebaser wrote it, but i don't understand why there is no such clear documentation inside of official documentation. The docs is beautiful, but sometimes hard to understand why such important info is not there.. ]:

For Zenko's comment, i guess write 'inside of {}' would be subject to billing since Frank's answer is suggesting that the data only involved in trigger is free. I understand that there is no way to include write ops into that trigger. So it seems that we've got no way to write data within the very free trigger at the time of writing.. ]: