# Does Firebase Realtime Database charge for Writing / Uploading data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is another question similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60076705/does-firebase-function-reading-and-writing-to-firebase-realtime-database-contrib)

But the answer does not satisfy my question. I'm asking specifically about the writing operations in Realtime DB. I know that reads / downloads will be billed.

However the [Realtime Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) does not mention 'uploads' or 'writes'. It only mention: downloads, storage and simultaneous connection.

But how about upload (a.k.a writes)?
Does it mean that it is free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are ***sort of*** free.

As you already know, the [pricing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) only mentions charges for

- Simultaneous connections
- GB stored
- GB downloaded

However, if you refer to the [Understanding Realtime Database Billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing), you can see that writes **contribute** to billing through connections and writing data using the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

It is different from Cloud Firestore in the sense that a single write does not generate billing charges, but writing can lead to them through other ways.