# Firebase and authentication pricing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm totally new to working with Firebase and have two simple questions about the **pricing** because I want to make sure I'm not exceeding my own price limit later on.

1. On the Firebase-Website it says in terms of **authentication** you're being charged per successful verification, does that mean I only have to pay every time a new user registers or do I also have to pay when an existing user is logging in or I'm retrieving data from a user profile?
2. Regarding the **Firebase Realtime Database** it says you're being charged depending on the amount of stored and downloaded data, so does that mean saving data to the Realtime Database is completely free and that I principally wouldn't have to worry about saving too many times?

(both are probably self-explaining, but I don't want to do any mistakes)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who still come across this question, here's a proper answer to my question:

1. The **authentication pricing** refers **only** to **phone authentication** since all other authentication services are free anyway. Which means, if you want to verify a user via SMS you will be charged for each verification after you have exceeded the monthly limit of 10k verifications.
2. This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62691171/does-firebase-realtime-database-charge-for-writing-uploading-data).

Answer (score 1):

1. Per verification means, per successful login
2. For the database, you have two options, Realtime Database (old) and Firestore (new). Realtime database is charged based on bandwidth and storage, while Firestore charges based on operations (daily 20k write, 50k read and 20k delete free of charges)

If you wanna learn more you can go to https://firebase.google.com/pricing & https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/firebase-cloud-firestore-v-s-firebase-realtime-database-931d4265d4b0

Answer (score 0):

As per the info from [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#pricing-paid-free-features)

Firebase's paid infrastructure products are the Realtime Database, Cloud Storage for Firebase, Cloud Functions, Hosting, Test Lab, and phone authentication. We offer a no-cost tier for all of these features.

Firebase also has many no-cost products: Analytics, Cloud Messaging, the Notifications composer, Remote Config, App Indexing, Dynamic Links, and Crash Reporting. You can use an unlimited amount of any of these products in all plans, including our no-cost Spark plan. `In addition, all Authentication features beyond phone authentication are no-cost.`