# Does the connection cost associated with writing to Firebase Realtime Database depend on the amount of data being written?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

*Note: There are similar SO questions related to costs associated with writing to Firebase Realtime Database (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62691171/does-firebase-realtime-database-charge-for-writing-uploading-data)), but I have a question that specifically relates to the relationship between write volume and the resulting connection cost.*

So according to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing), it looks like the Realtime Database does not directly charge for writing data, although "writes can lead to connection costs on your bill".

But I would like to know, are these connection costs variable - dependent on the amount of data being written? Or is it the same no matter the size.

For example, if I update 10 MB of data once every minute, will this result in the same cost as writing only 10KB of data once every minute?

I'm trying to figure out what degree of "write-efficiency" is worth my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked suggests an answer.  Under "Protocol overhead" it states:

> Each time a connection is established, this overhead, combined with any SSL encryption overhead, contributes to the connection costs. Although this isn't a lot of bandwidth for a single request, it can be a substantial part of your bill if your payloads are tiny or you make frequent, short connections.

This is pretty clearly saying that, due to necessary protocol overhead, frequent connections incur more expense than a single connection.  It doesn't say that the connection costs are variable based on the size of the payload being written, so it stands to reason that the connection cost is fairly static.  Think HTTP headers that are essentially the same for each connection.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm not that familiar with backend lingo so I wasn't originally sure if this answered my question or not.

Comment: So would it be logical to assume that writing 10KB of data twice would be more expensive than updating 100KB of data once?

Comment: They're not really comparable since you're writing more data in the second case, which costs more to store over time.  It's more reasonable to compare 10+10 to 20.  Given the same total amount of data, fewer connections to get there would be less expensive in the end.

Comment: Good point. I guess I was assuming 100KB of data was already stored in either case, and the write was just an update to the data. But from your comment, it looks like less connections would result in less cost in either case. Kinda strange if you think about it! Updating your entire database once is less costly than updating a single key-value pair twice. Weird......

Comment: Please confirm if my above comment is correct, because it just seems so strange.

Comment: It's not so much the number of operations as it is the number of connections.  The SDK will use a single connection to process multiple reads and writes pipelined over that single connection, until the single connection must drop for some reason.   Unless you're talking about many thousands of connections daily, you're worrying about an amount of data that you won't even be able to detect in your billing.  The documentation is basically trying to tell you: batch up your work over a single connection if you can, as that single connection is cheaper than spreading it out over mulitple.

Comment: Perfect. You rock man, thanks